# Dynamically create apparmor hats/profiles

Tags: security, linux-kernel, profile, apparmor

We run an application inside apparmor which executes users code, when we execute user code I would like to dynamically generate a profile which limits their write access to a directory based on their user id.

Does apparmor support this well? The only way I can think of doing this is by creating a temp profile with the appropriate entry restricting their permissions and restarting the apparmor daemon. Is there a better way to do this? It seems like overkill.

Comment: I found out about http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man3/aa_kernel_interface.3.html
which seem to be exactly what I need